# MySQL and PHP login security concerns

Tags: php, mysql

I've been lurking here a few months now and have to say this community rocks!

So, here's my question. I'm working on creating a log in function for a web site. It's just a very basic forum at this point, my goal is to learn each piece and grow them from there, not dive right into the deep end.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$username = "temp_name";
$password = "temp_pass";
$hostname = "temp_host";
$db_name = "temp_dbase";
$tbl_name = "temp_tbl";

$login_uname = $_POST['username'];
$login_upass = $_POST['password'];
$salt1 = "temp_salt1";
$salt2 = "temp_salt2";

mysql_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password")or die("Unable to connect to server);
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("Cannot access database.");

$user = mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM $tbl_name WHERE username = '$login_uname');
$userexist = mysql_num_rows($user);

if($userexists == 0) {
    die("Invalid login information.");
}

$userinfo = mysql_fetch_array($user);

$checkpass = md5($login_upass);
$checkpass = $salt1 . $checkpass . $salt2;

if(($userinfo['username'] == $login_uname) && ($userinfo['password'] == $checkpass)) {
    setcookie('username', "$login_uname", time()+60*60*24*7);
    setcookie('password', "$login_upass", time()+60*60*24*7);
}
else
    die("Invalid login information.");

?>
```

Now, the code works, no issues. I understand the basics of hashing and salting passwords (I know md5 isn't ideal, but for now it's just a learning tool.) My real concern is this:

I have my MySQL login information right there in my code! I considered just having users register a username and password and actually getting MySQL to generate a login username and password to itself for them granting appropriate permissions, but I feel this is wholly impractical and a security risk unto itself as the site expands.

Hiding the code in another file and just using an  might work, but does using this method prevent users from being able to browse my code itself and just looking at the basic MySQL login information?

I know that PHP code isn't displayed in a web site's source code, unless it isn't parsed correctly. But are there any concerns or solutions I should be aware of?

Thanks again for the help! I know this was a wall of text.

Comment: This question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since you are basically looking for comments on current working code.

Comment: First things first you should probably stray away from the mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. Try the PDO class or mysqli_* functions

Comment: I agree with @MikeBrant.  You're looking for a code review.  Lots of obvious issues with your code.  First off, you don't hash the pw then add salts to it as a string.  You add the salt to the underlying pw and then hash it. You should store a unique salt for each user and store it in the user row.   I also don't know why you are setting cookies with the name/pw.  Horrible idea.  Use sessions for state.  Even if you want a remember me feature, you should generate a key for that and store it in the user row.

Comment: Since this is working I'm assuming the issue was a bad copy/paste but all your queries are missing the closing double quote.

Comment: If you've been lurking for a few months, surely you've seen the constant stream of comments made about SQL injection and use of the deprecated MySQL extension, and about password hashing?

Comment: You realize you are storing the unhashed version of the password in the cookie right?

Comment: Hey all, thanks for the responses! Sorry, I did post in the wrong section, but thank you all for the help regardless! Also, in regards to the issue of salt first, hash later, I just typed it in badly, same goes for the missing double quotes. I'll also check out the sessions stuff mentioned by gview! Thanks again, everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Externalize the configuration information into something like `config.php` then use `require_once('config.php');` at the top of your file.

CHMOD (change mode) the config.php file to 0644 so that it cannot be executed or read except by the owning user (the server).

With that in place, no one will be able to see your MySQL connection information unless they have FTP or SSH access to your box (at that point, you've got bigger problems)